# Module Development - Get ID of a field within a Matrix field

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, matrix, plugin-supertable

I have a matrix field that has a Supertable matrix within it.

I need to programatically get the ID of the field that is nested in the Matrix.

I have the code below:

```
$matrixField = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('myMatrixFieldHandle');
```

Which gets me my Matrix field element, but I can't figure out how to get the fields that are within that Matrix field and thus the ID of the field within the Matrix field.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through the fields in the blocktype definition for your Matrix field. For simplicities sake, I've supplied a loop, which you can cut-down if you have a specific block type in mind you just want to fetch for:

```
$matrixField = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('myMatrixFieldHandle');

foreach ($matrixField->getBlockTypes() as $key => $blockType) {
    Craft::dump($blockType->name);

    foreach ($blockType->getFields() as $key => $field) {
        Craft::dump($field->name);
    }
}
```